# JSON Schema use values from document in schema

Tags: jsonschema

Assume we have a json document

```
{
  ips: ['192.168.1.1','192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3'],
  active: '192.168.1.1'
}
```

Can I write a schema that asserts that `active` must be in the `ips`; hence the following would fail validation.

```
{
  ips: ['192.168.1.1','192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3'],
  active: '192.168.1.4'
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create JSON schema for validate if given field of type string contains value from given string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70055236/how-to-create-json-schema-for-validate-if-given-field-of-type-string-contains-va)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible using the pure JSON schema standard if the set of ips is known. In this case, you can define an `enum` of IP values and use it to validate the `active` property. See also: http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#id4

You could use JSONPatch to update your schema if the set of IPs is changing. Afterward, apply the validation.